# For what values of $x$ will $ax^2+b$ be perfect squares?

Tags: number-theory

I need help on the this.

Suppose that $ax^2+b$ is given where $a, b\in \mathbb Z$. Can we determine all the values of $x\in \mathbb Z$ such that $ax^2+b$ will be a perfect square ?

Please help me. In case problem like this has been solved before, kindly provide me the links.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds like the generalized Pell's equation. Try looking that up for some info.

Comment: You can find some solution using Pythagorean triples, as: $6^2+8^2=10^2 \rightarrow 4x^2+64=10^2$ for $x=9$, but maybe there are other solutions...

Comment: solve in integers: $ax^2 - y^2 = b$  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8684/generalized-pells-equation-why-is-4-special

Comment: Thank you all. The information were helpful. Between, why close vote 3?

Comment: I'd guess the close votes come from people who are annoyed that you haven't shown any evidence that you've worked on the problem at all yourself before asking other people to solve it for you.

Comment: I got it. Thanks for the information